# Describing Quotient Ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

**Problem**. Let $I=(x-y)$ and $J=(x+y)$. Describe $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$, $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/J$, $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(I+J)$, $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/IJ$ as polynomial functions on a certain subset in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

I was given the hint to make the change of variables $x'=x+y$ and $y'=x-y$, but I am having difficulties describing these.

Comment: $\phi(f (x,y) ) = f(x+y,y)$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$, where does it send $\Bbb{C}[x,y], I$ and $\Bbb{C}[x,y]/ I$ ?

Comment: Im having tough time seeing even this. I dont know how to describe that in any useful way